# Feature with Content Types is not reverted

Tags: features

I am stuck watching the Feature state as Overriden. I tried different solutions as:

- Disable and re-enable the feature
- Restart apache to ensure the APC cache is cleared
- Clear All caches from Drupal administration

But I get stcuk with the overriden state.

Doing a Diff within the Diff module, I see the following differences:

[image]

But if I check the current feature code the Line 732 doesn't seems to be the same as the Diff module is detecting.

[image]

So I don't understand where is the difference.

I do the revert of the feature, clear cache, ... several times, and the Feature is always on Overriden state.

Please, any idea to discover the reason why I can't do the revert and a solution to perform the revert?

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether there are two copies mistakenly placed inside drupal modules. Just recreate the feature with a new name and a version number. Download new feature then disable current feature and remove module completely from source. Then make sure the feature is completely removed and not appearing in the module list. Then add new feature and see.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your suggestion, but I would like to find the way to do it without recreating, what I had already into account but I wanted to skip it. Mainly to have a better understanding of the reason. This is a kind of "format windows" solution ... lol. Anyway, since I have had to do other stuffs and I have had to recreate the whole DB, now the state is correct.